Proof of $|\kappa_{s}(t)|=\kappa(t)$ and book recommendation on differential geometry

Definition: If $\gamma:I \to R^2$ is a regular plane curve (not necessarliy parametrized by arc length), then for all $t \in I,$ $\kappa_s(t)=\frac{\left<a(t),R_{90}\left(\frac{v(t)}{|v(t)|}\right)\right>}{|v(t)|^2}$.

I am trying to  prove $|\kappa_{s}(t)|=\kappa(t)=|\frac{a^{\bot}(t)}{v(t)^2}|$. Only need to show: $\left<a(t),R_{90}\left(\frac{v(t)}{|v(t)|}\right)\right>=\pm |a^{\bot}|.$
$Attempt:$ Writing $a(t)=a^{||}(t)+a^{\bot}(t)=\frac{<a(t),v(t)>}{|v(t)|}v(t)+a^{\bot}(t),$ where $a^{||}(t)$ is parallel to $v(t)$ and $a^{\bot}(t)$ is perpendicular to $v(t)$.  Then I got the following: $\left<a(t),R_{90}\left(\frac{v(t)}{|v(t)|}\right)\right>=<a^{\bot}(t),R_{90}\left(\frac{v(t)}{|v(t)|}\right)> \overset{?}{=}\pm |a^{\bot}|$, which is my confusion part. $$\text{Just use the formula}<x,y>=|x||y|\cos(\theta)$$
$\textbf{More}$: I am learning differential geometry using Kristopher Tapp's book by myself. I know it is important to solve problems, otherwise, I wouldn't have a deep understanding. However, this book has no answer, if I do the exercises in this book, I don't know whether I do correct or not, seems to be meaningless. So could someone recommend some books with solutions for undergraduates, thanks a lot.

What is $R_{90}$ here?

@user1008978 Rotate 90 degrees counterclockwise

Thus in this case $R_{90}(v(t)/\vert\vert v(t) \vert \vert)$ is the unit vector perpendicular to $v(t)$. Hence the inner product of this unit vector with the perpendicular component of $a(t)$ is exactly its length.

I learned of Tapp's book only by answering some questions on this site about errors in it. It seems to be generally a very nice text, but beware of errors. You might also try my free text, linked in my profile, but I have answers only to selected exercises. A popular book that is well known for having solutions to its exercises is A. Pressley's Undergraduate Differential Geometry.

@TedShifrin Thank you very much!
